# Is there a way to add profile2 forms in multistep registration

Tags: users, forms

Is there a way to add profile2 forms into a multistep registration form?... 
First of all I am a beginner I only know small tidbits on how to do multistep...
What I need is step 1 to be basic user registration information, step 2 to be personal profile2 info and a conditional set up basically asking the viewer something in a radio or click box that should process if they need a second profile. If that conditional is met then they go to step 3 and fill out a second profile2 form.

[I found out about multistep here](http://grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7#comment-245)

Comment: if you could just help me with the inserting of profile 2 form into this multi-step form i could probably find out about the rest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes definately we can create profile2 field as a multistep form for this we can use [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group)
By field group module you can include all fields in multipage group and after that create multipage group as per you need and include relevant fields in each break.

Comment: where do I start with this... It seems as though you are speaking about a module along side fieldgroup?