# How to customize registration process in Drupal 7?

Tags: users

I want to customize default registration process in Drupal 7. The registration process includes 3 steps:

1. Show some account types (in a page or form?). For example "personal", "business", "organization"... And users will choose their own account type.
2. Fill information into registration form. Each account type which users choose in step 1 has some corresponding fields.
3. Finish registration with an confirmation email or something else.

The registration process is similar to https://secure.payza.com/signup

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can create three roles named:

- Personal
- Business
- Organization

Now you can use [profile2 Registration Path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module. This module will give you three separate profile for each roles. You can add separate fields for each profile. And from the configuration of profile pages you can enable separate registration path also.

Thus you can have three registration path for three roles and three registration forms also.

Now to create multistep form for profile2 module you can follow [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48411/is-there-a-way-to-add-profile2-forms-in-multistep-registration) from this site.

Answer (score 0):

That requires quite a lot customization.

Here is a tutorial you may find helpful.

http://grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7

And there is an module for that:

Multi-step forms:
h[ttp://drupal.org/project/mforms](http://drupal.org/project/mforms)