# how to add fields for drupal registration form internally souce code of drupal7.17 application

Tags: forms, users

generally all you are editing template in this location  files `C:\wamp\www\drupal\themes\bartik\template.php`
i think so ...
so please guide me how to create customise registration form step by step in this folder
like adding fields like

- first name:-
- last name:-
- date of birth:-
- email:-
- user name:-
- password:-
- confirm password:-
- location:-
- referer:-

{not graphically using  wampserver opening site and login go to configuration/managefields}.
show me code method where we insert source code

example:-like using other applications 
home.html,about us.html,form.html,contact.html

we are interlinking these pages..
generally we insert username password field in first page
if the user is not register we will add one more option signup
,when user click signup it will display registartion form 
like this i want to create ....how it is possible
and also show database connectivity in dos command base 
by using my sql software application

not in wamp server application ....create database

please any one suggest me  step by step using bartik theme.... or others.

thank you in advance
& sorry for bad english

Comment: Same type of questions have been asked - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49582/how-to-customize-registration-process-in-drupal-7/

Comment: If by customizing you mean adding form fields to the form, then that is not done in a template file.

Answer (score 1):

To add the fields to user profile you should use [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module.

- With profile2 user account settings and user profiles are
  conceptually different things, e.g. with the "Profile pages" module
  enabled users get two separate menu links "My account" and "My
  profile".
- Profile2 allows for creating multiple profile types, which may be
  assigned to roles via permissions (e.g. a general profile + a
  customer profile)
- Profile2 supports private profile fields, which are only shown to the
  user owning the profile and to administrators.

Comment: ok how to insert module in that and install show me the process how to do is it able to change fields and inerlink to database.....if it is so please show me the process of source code and connect to database by my sql in dos command base because i wnat to use it to store ...

Comment: but u given profile2 module while after install only it will display ...without module can it possible to do .. i want to insert code of registartion form actually if i want to add fields in the files like ex:-template.php  internally code where can i... do it add more fields manually that must dispaly.....or show me the code where i want to change to put fields

Comment: In drupal we don't have to add seperate code for each form. There is default registration form. and profile2 module will add fields to the form.